# Create PDF pages in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Which is the best PHP-PDF library that can be used to create PDF files with more than 100 pages?

I am creating an application where there is need of creating PDF reports of account for an entire financial year, which library should is use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the best PDF library for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php)

Comment: Not duplicate, since the other question is 2 years older and the old answers are not necessarily recent either

Answer (score 5):

See here:

[Converting HTML to PDF using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/converting-html-to-pdf-using-php)

[Which one is the best PDF-API for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/best-pdf-generator-in-php-mpdf-or-fpdf)

[HTML to PDF vs. Programmatically creating PDF via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812484/html-to-pdf-vs-programmatically-creating-pdf-via-php)

[Converting HTML to PDF (not PDF to HTML) using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403820/html-to-pdf-not-pdf-to-html-in-php)

Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20pdf

Comment: I like how this post now comes up in the very search you posted :) I thought that was the exact problem SO was trying to solve..

Answer (score 1):

Use tcpdf library. It might be best for you.