# How can I export my php page to PDF using php?

Tags: php, pdf

My php page has a lot of variables and style sheet and html tables are also there. I know that there are some opensource pdf class like fpdf, but when it comes to php variables and when I need to pull data from mysql table, I have no idea how to put them together. I have no knowledge in pdf class also. I have also search in internet and could not find what could be the best option to start with for a newbie like me. So any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fpdf

Comment: @brasofilo I will do it...

Comment: @brasofilo I have gone through few of them and think that I need to learn fpdf class. But I sometimes think that there might the easy way out. Fpdf class is a little bit complex for newbie like us.

Comment: @LalhriatpuiiMapuii: search on SO with `[php] html to pdf` yielded this very interesting thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365698/create-pdf-pages-in-php Comvert HTML to PDF with PHP two methods in the top answer

Comment: First, try something for yourself and ask later. Recommendation questions are off-topic. Myself, almost never have to ask, there's lots of good resources here at [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/) class.

Just download mpdf class and use the following script to print your php page. Save the below code as mypdfgenerator.php.:

```
<?php 
include("mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('win-1252','A4','','',15,10,16,10,10,10);//A4 page in portrait for landscape add -L.
$mpdf->SetHeader('|Your Header here|');
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');// Giving page number to your footer.
$mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;    // false is default
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// Buffer the following html with PHP so we can store it to a variable later
ob_start();
?>
<?php include "phppage.php";
 //This is your php page ?>
<?php 
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// send the captured HTML from the output buffer to the mPDF class for processing
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
//$mpdf->SetProtection(array(), 'user', 'password'); uncomment to protect your pdf page with password.
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I will test your code. First let me download the class.

Comment: @LalhriatpuiiMapuii If you aim to use it for offline purpose or something not to be printed dynamically in a site, you can opt for [Universal Document Converter](www.print-driver.com/‎).

Comment: How easy is to use this MPDF class, it also has good documentation. Thank you. I think this is what I am looking for.